# How to paste over column by separate matching column

Tags: awk, join, merge, bioinformatics

I have these two files:

```
    file1.txt  
    0 rs3094315 0 0 C T  
    0 rs12562034 0 0 A G  
    0 rs3934834 0 0 C T  

    file2.txt  
    Chr,Pos,snp_name  
    1, 742429,rs3094315
```

Where the first column of file1 is also a Chr column, and has to be replaced by file2 chr column. However, it has to match snp to that it looks like this:

```
    file3  
    1 rs3094315 0 0 C T
```

File2 has different row and column numbers.

Answer (score 0):

already answered partially here --
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24516141/awk-processing-2-files-with-different-field-separators

```
awk 'NR==FNR {arr[$2]=$2FS$3FS$4FS$5FS$6; next} {print $1,arr[$3]}' file1 FS="," file2 
1 rs3094315 0 0 C T
```

Comment: unfortunately, this did not work. It listed all the values for chr from file2 in terminal. I maybe have to use something else for this merge. Thank you for your help

Comment: not sure if it has something to do with the awk version, because it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Using `join` and a shell that understands process substitutions:

```
$ join -t ' ' -1 2 -2 3 -o2.1,0,1.3,1.4,1.5,1.6 <( sort -k2 file1 ) <( tr ',' ' ' <file2 | sort -k3 )
1 rs3094315 0 0 C T
```

The second file, `file2`, has a problem in that it uses a different field delimiter from the first file, `file1`.  This is remedied by running its content through `tr` to replace all commas with spaces.

The two files are then sorted on the fields that we're going to join the data on; field 2 in the first file, and field 3 in the second file.

The `join` will then read these two datasets and join them on the specified spaces-separated fields.

The output fields are determined by the `-o` flag, and we pick the first field  of the second file, the join field, followed by fields 3 through to 6 from the first file.